# asp.net compare validator date sunday

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, datetime

I'm developing an web application with asp.net and c#. I have a textbox in my page and it inputs a simple date. I've used CompareValidator to validate this textbox, but when the user input an specific date (3rd sunday of october, e.g.: 10/16/2011 or 10/17/2010 or 10/18/2009) the compare validator says it is invalid date. Does someone knows what is happening with it ?

My compare validator:

```
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cvDataProtocolo" runat="server" 
     ControlToValidate="txtDataProtocolo" Display="Dynamic" 
     ErrorMessage="Data Inválida" 
     SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
     ValidationGroup="vProtocolo"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

**Edits-----**

Yes, I wrote 10/16/2011 just to understand, my culture is setup to pt-BR (portuguese Brazil) and in Brazil we use the format dd/MM/yyyy and the CompareValidator does not valid 16/10/2011 (in format dd/MM/yyyy) as a valid format. I've setted my culture in my webform:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture() {
    Page.Culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("pt-BR").ToString();
    Page.UICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("pt-BR").ToString();

    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("pt-BR");
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New CultureInfo("pt-BR");
}
```

Thank you

Comment: May be the validaror use a different date format...

Comment: @Max: But that would not only fail with few date values but with all.

Comment: @Tim no if the current format is like this dd/MM/yyyy, 10/18/2011 is bad value but 10/11/2011 is good (but it's not october)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have set your Culture correctly, as (for instance) in the UK, 10/16/2011 means the 10th day of the 16th month, which would be an invalid date.

See here for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx

Comment: So, which dates validate? Is it only the three dates you mention in your post, or more? Does 01/01/2011 validate?

Answer (score 0):

CompareValidator use the CultureInfo of the current thread to get your date format. If you want to use a specific colture and date format, add this declaration to your page:

```
<%@ Page culture="your culture" %>
```